# How to unit test that an UI-based event has been raised?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, mstest

I would like to write unit tests with MSTest that verifies that a certain event has been called after a control element has been changed. Unfortunately with the code below the event handler "comboBoxComPort_SelectedIndexChanged" for the comboBoxComPort (which is a WinForms Control) never gets called. This of course results in the anonymous handler in the test code not being called.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ComboBoxComPort_SelectionChanged_DirtyEventFired()
{
    ConfigUI target = new ConfigUI();
    var accessibleTarget = new PrivateObject(target);
    ComboBox comboBoxComPort = (ComboBox)accessibleTarget.GetField("comboBoxComPort");

    bool dirtyEventCalled = false;
    target.DirtyEvent += delegate
    {
        dirtyEventCalled = true;
    };

    comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = comboBoxComPort.Items.Count - 1;

    Assert.IsTrue(dirtyEventCalled);
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume this is the "SelectedIndexChanged"-handler:

```
public class ConfigUI
{
     [...]

     private void comboBoxComPort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         DirtyEvent();
     }
 }
```

Can anybody tell me why the testing fails? I am aware that accessing private members in unit tests is in general not a good idea, but I don't see a better way of testing the UI-behaviour. Suggestions on this are also welcome of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is your registered handler right?

```
 target.DirtyEvent += delegate
{
    dirtyEventCalled = true;
};
```

If the event is indeed raised, it doesn't mean the handler will be called when the event is not allowed to "bubble or tunnel"... Depending on the context, events can be considered Handled when the first handler receives control.  WPF is particularly picky with this concept, forcing the handler to set the ISHandled bit to false in order for the event to float elsewhere.

If you can; set breakpoints in the first handler of the event, and then in the test of that event.  Restart the application, and ensure first that the first handler is seeing it. Take a  look at the event data in that handler prior to exiting. Upon exit of the first handler, if your test handler is not called it's because the event is considered "satisfied".  This should get you closer to finding the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not completely sure that I get what you mean by "first handler". I tried debugging into the code and the basic problem is that "comboBoxComPort_SelectedIndexChanged" does not get called (verified by setting a breakpoint there), which in my eyes should happen after the line

comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = comboBoxComPort.Items.Count - 1;

Also I'm using WinForms.

Comment: The first handler to see the event will be the one that is registered first, set a break point there (if you can) in the code of application (not the test code) then follow what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a interface for the ConfigUI class (since you want to see that a control invokes a method on that class, right?), then use the Moq library to mock ConfigUI in the test and use the Moq.Verify to see that the method was invoked (you can ask verify to say how many times and so on...)